# Scaling gradle tasks for multiple device support

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, adb, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

My current setup for instrumentation tests cannot handle the screenshots saved to each device during test sharding. It doesn't know what to do because it detects multiple devices, and so those tasks all fail. I'm trying to figure out how to scale it so regardless of how many devices are being used to run my tests, whether it's one or a dozen, screenshots are grabbed from each device and moved to a single folder in my HTML report. I'm guessing I need to somehow pass the device name when I run ./gradlew cAT, so it can slap it onto all the other tasks I run as a prefix.

**So that's my question and you don't have to read anymore if you already know how to answer it.**

I have several assumptions, including:
1. My screenshot grabbing code (see below) is set up properly (and should not be scrapped entirely)
2. I'm running shards properly. So far I open a bunch of emulators, grab their names with "adb devices" in the terminal which returns something like:

```
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
emulator-5556   device
emulator-5558   device
```

Then I open three separate terminals and run one of the below commands in each terminal:

```
ANDROID_SERIAL=emulator-5554 ./gradlew cAT -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.numShards=3 -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.shardIndex=0
ANDROID_SERIAL=emulator-5556 ./gradlew cAT -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.numShards=3 -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.shardIndex=1
ANDROID_SERIAL=emulator-5558 ./gradlew cAT -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.numShards=3 -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.shardIndex=2
```

Then the tests run on the emulators and gradle creates a single HTML test report, mashing all of their results together by what I assume is magic.

## Previous setup

As of now, I just run it without sharding. I take a screenshot when a test fails. This is saved to the device. I run the tests with the standard ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest (or ./gradlew cAT) and have tasks that follow it to pull the screenshots off the device and store them in the HTML report. It's kind of a mess and could use some work, but that code looks like this:

TestCase file that takes a screenshot when a test fails:

```
@Rule
public TestName name = new TestName();

@Rule
public TestWatcher watchman = new TestWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
        screenshotFailedTest(name.getMethodName());
    }};

public void screenshotFailedTest(String testName) {
    File path = new File(getScreenshotPath());
    if (!path.exists()) {
        path.mkdirs(); }
    UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
    device.takeScreenshot(new File(path, testName));
}

private String getScreenshotPath() {
    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/screenshots/" + getTargetContext().getPackageName();
}
```

My nightmare gradle file's tasks that handle the screenshots on the device:

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
if (task.name.startsWith('connectedAndroidTest') || (task.name.startsWith('connected') && task.name.contains('AndroidTest'))) {
    println "Starting Connected Android Tests"
    task.finalizedBy screenshotFailedTests
}}

task createScreenshotFolder(type: Exec) {
    commandLine './create_screenshot_folder.sh'
    // see script below
}

task copyScreenshots(type: Exec) {
    def adb = android.sdkDirectory.path + "/platform-tools/adb"
    executable "$adb"
    args "pull",
        "/storage/emulated/0/screenshots/<app.name>/",
        "${buildDir}/reports/androidTests/connected/flavors/INTERNAL/"
}

task removeScreenshotsFromDevice(type: Exec) {
    def adb = android.sdkDirectory.path + "/platform-tools/adb"
    executable "$adb"
    args "shell",
         "rm",
         "-r",
         "/storage/emulated/0/screenshots/<app.name>/"
}

task renameScreenshotFolder {
    doLast {
    file("${buildDir}/reports/androidTests/connected/flavors/INTERNAL/<app.name>").renameTo(file("${buildDir}/reports/androidTests/connected/flavors/INTERNAL/Screenshots"))
}}

task screenshotFailedTests {
    dependsOn 'createScreenshotFolder'
    dependsOn 'copyScreenshots'
    dependsOn 'removeScreenshotsFromDevice'
    dependsOn 'renameScreenshotFolder'
    tasks.findByName('copyScreenshots').mustRunAfter 'createScreenshotFolder'
    tasks.findByName('removeScreenshotsFromDevice').mustRunAfter 'copyScreenshots'
    tasks.findByName('renameScreenshotFolder').mustRunAfter 'removeScreenshotsFromDevice'
}
```

And then the create_screenshot_folder.sh script referenced above:

```
# Call adb and check if folder exists, create if it doesn't
cd $ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/
./adb shell "if [ -e /storage/emulated/0/screenshots/ ]; then echo Screenshot folder already exists; else mkdir /storage/emulated/0/screenshots/ && echo Creating screenshot folder; fi"

./adb shell "if [ -e /storage/emulated/0/screenshots/<app.name>/ ]; then echo The screenshot folder already exists; else mkdir /storage/emulated/0/screenshots/<app.name>/ && echo Creating screenshot folder; fi"
```

It's rather messy and maybe there's a much simpler way to do all of that without external libraries, but it seems to do just fine for a single device.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried running the tests via

> ./gradlew spoonTaskname

That takes care of the sharding automatically and you can eliminate that part from your framework. Also, it should also take care of pulling all the screenshots from the emulators/devices and merge them to the final report.

Comment: I want to avoid using any third party libraries, including Spoon.